# How to extract a string always comes after specific string and optionally followed by a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, search

If I have a string the is always preceded by `http://`, and optionally folowed by `/`. Example:

```
http://www.mymovies.com/
```

But sometimes can be in the format:
    http://www.mymovies.com

I want to extract `www.mymoviews.com` 
I want to capture both format (with/without the `/`)

I tried using:

```
import re
print(re.search('http://(.*)/','http://www.mymovies.com').group(1))
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

1) How to solve the error 
2) How to capture both with/without the following `/` character (as my solution requires `/`

Comment: `re.search('www.+com',s).group()`

Comment: It is not always `www.` my fixed character is `http://` as I stated in the question.

Comment: Try `http://([^/]*)/?`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aKWdre/1)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew How to try it? using re? Can you write the full line plz.

Comment: Yes, `re` is enough. `print(re.search(r'http://([^/]*)/?','http://www.mymovies.com').group(1))` and `print(re.search(r'http://([^/]*)/?','http://www.mymovies.com/').group(1))`. I do not know what other types of URLs you want to match, thus, it is a suggestion.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  Why small r before the string?

Comment: See [What exactly is a “raw string regex” and how can you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it). In such a string literal, all ``\`` are treated as literal backslashes. [Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334871/why-do-python-regex-strings-sometimes-work-without-using-raw-strings) if you are intrigued. Well, consider `r` a best practice when defining regex patterns in Python.

Comment: Do you have any more test cases? Any set of rules of what kind of input the regex should match or avoid matching?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew yours is correct answer. The error appears because the string starts with `http://` and my actual code was `https://`. To capture both `http` and `https://` I did it like this: `http(s?)://([^/]*)/?` as some strings may have `http://` while others may have `https://`

Comment: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934446/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
m = re.search(r'https?://([^/]*)/?','http://www.mymovies.com')
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aKWdre/2)

**Details**

- `http` - `http` substring
- `s?` - 1 or 0 `s` chars
- `://` - a `://` substring
- `([^/]*)` - Capturing group 1: zero or more chars other than `/`
- `/?` - 1 or 0 `/` chars.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/qAR6xt) (prints four `www.mymovies.com` as output):

```
import re
strs = ['http://www.mymovies.com/','http://www.mymovies.com','https://www.mymovies.com/','https://www.mymovies.com']
r = re.compile(r'https?://([^/]*)/?')
for s in strs:
    m = r.search('http://www.mymovies.com')
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Comment: Do you mean http - https substring (you forgot 's')

Comment: @user9371654 I have not forgotten `s`, see `https?` in the pattern: it matches `http` or `https` since `s?` matches an optional `s`, i.e. 1 or 0 `s` chars.

Comment: can u double check the first bullet point? this is what I mean.

Comment: @user9371654 It is fine, since it is followed with the second bullet point. Please see the pattern in its entirety.

Comment: Now I got what you mean. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your search string is `http://(.*)/`, so the `/` at the end is obligatory. If you put a `?` after it you make it optional, or you can just leave it out completely. If you don't want it to be part of the resulting string, either restrict the matched characters before it to everything but `/`:

```
https://([^/]*)
```

or do a simple last-character-check after the operation and remove it if it's a `/`:

```
if result[-1] == "/": result = result[:-1]
```

It should also be noted that if your input can be full URLs (including paths and `?key=value` pairs), you should restrict the matched characters further.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(?<=http:\/\/)\[^\/\]+?(?=\/|$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MJkVs4/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without regular expressions using the split() method:

```
url.split("/")[2]

'http://www.mymovies.com/'.split("/")[2] ==> "www.mymovies.com"

'http://www.mymovies.com'.split("/")[2] ==> "www.mymovies.com"

'http://www.mymovies.com/star-wars/episodeV'.split("/")[2] ==> "www.mymovies.com"
```